# SugarCRM Setting

Tags: sugarcrm

I use two different email address (different domain) in my work, both releated to existing companies. I want to use a web application like sugracrm to manage all my contacts.

Should I setup two sugarcrm installation for both account or I can use just one without mixing up things?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you are looking to manage your contacts for two different companies.  So you have some contacts you keep track of as Company A and other contacts you keep track of as Company B.  The contacts themselves can each belong to whatever company/account they belong to, right?

If you have two different businesses, I would recommend having two different CRMs, not because Sugar can't handle it, but because it's not a great idea to manage to companies on one CRM (regardless of the CRM you choose).

However, I can reccomend a simple solution to keep it all in one instance of Sugar:

Create a custom module with a template of "Company". Call it something like "My Companies" or something.

After launching the module, enter your two companies as separate records.

Finally, create a one-to-many relationship between the "My Company" module and the "Contacts" module.  This will allow you to choose which of your two companies a contact belongs to and allow you to filter out contacts to see only those for one or the other company.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What do you think about running SugarCRM on a shared hosting in terms of performances?

Comment: The real performance hit I've seen with Sugar is when you have MySQL set to ISAM instead of InnoDB.  The only other thing to watch out for in terms of performance is if you are using tons of middleware, like the the Outlook plugin.  But if you just have a handful of users, I think shared hosting is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sugar is very good at segregating information if I'm interpreting your question correctly you needs will be meet sugars structure.

```
     Company A                            Company B
  Contact 1 Contact2                Contact 3 Contact 4            Contact 5
```

Best thing to do is to go have a play with a demo instance on there site

Comment: I think the way you are reading it is he has contacts for two companies (as in the contacts work for that company).  The way I read it, he has two separate businesses he runs and wants to track contacts for both.

Comment: Yes. But I would work with Contact1 with info@company1.com and Contact2 with info@company2.com. No way to mix up. If I login Sugarcm with credential1 I won't see contact1 and vice-versa. Maybe better having 2 intallation. But before all this I want to be sure of perforamances. I have just ordered the IMAP service. Now I can see in email folder message for business1 and business2. BTW in Home i can't see any email in My Email Dashboard even if in Email there are....

Answer (score 0):

If using paid version of Sugar, the best method would be to use the Teams feature.
Create a different team for each company.